# Where is the "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys" setting stored in Windows?

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7, in the Control Panel at `Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use` there is a checkbox labeled "Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys."

Where is that setting stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its stored in the registry value `On` in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Preference`

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply to the explorer context (right-click) menu!?